# Redirect user from TabBar to login viewController if he's not logged in (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I want to redirect user **after clicking on a TabBar item** based on his status (logged in or not). If he's logged in he'll get the standard view that goes with the tabBar, if he's not he'll get the login ViewController instead.
With some searches I found that the solution is to implement a custom TabBarController class however I couldn't find any clue about how to achieve that.

A more developed explanation or example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class for your `UITabBarController` and set the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to `self`

Then just implement the following function

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
  // Your code here
}
```